# WordPress - How to make taxonomy archive pages show in search results

Tags: wordpress, search, taxonomy

I am trying to make custom taxonomy archive pages show in native search results in WordPress. So basically the pages should show up in the search results exactly like posts.
What is the best way to achieve that?

To make this clear, I am not trying to make the posts show based on the title of the category. What I want is showing the taxonomy archive link in the results, same as a regular post would look like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for the same and found that you have to work on "Search Template" of Wordpress. I also suggest you to visit : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228645/how-to-add-custom-taxonomy-to-search